# How do I get it to print out the total grade?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I added in the 'int' like it was suggested as shown below

```
  import csv
  with open("./student_grades.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
  data = csv.reader(csvfile)
  print("Banner Total Grade")
   print("---------------------------------")
  for row in data:
  grade = int(row['Math']) + int(row['Physics']) + int(row['Chemistry']) + int(row['Biology'])
  print(row['banner'], grade)
```

After I add in int now I'm getting a value error

```
    ValueError                                
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [135], in <cell line: 7>()
      5   print("Banner Total Grade")
      6   print("---------------------------------")
    ----> 7 for row in data:
      8     grade = int(row['Math']) + int(row['Physics']) + int(row['Chemistry']) + int(row['Biology'])
      9 print(row['banner'], grade)

    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: You will need to convert the strings read from file to integer before the addition.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `int(row['Math']) + int(row['Physics']) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast each of the grades into integer. For example,

```
   int(row['maths'])
```

and if  your grades are in float then you can use float as well.

Comment: Thank it worked as a float